# "missing \begin{document}" and "something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item"

Tags: document-classes, overleaf

I am using the overleaf template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sample-policy-memo-for-cornell-info-1200/kybzqhsxjgjk and received some errors after making some modifications to it. I have been trying to fix it but failing. Hoping to get some help thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{texMemo} % originally by Rob Oakes; adapted by Alice Chen
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\title{Discovering}
\author{Name}
\email{email} % missing \begin{document}

\begin{document}
\maketitle % something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item

\section*{Introduction}
Some text for introduction. \cite{35usc101}
\section*{Research Question}
Some text for research question.

\section*{Methodology}
Some text for methodology.

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `texMemo` is not an official document class, and as far as I can see, your link just links to some document that *uses* this class, but not to the source of `texMemo.cls`. I think you should contact the `overleaf` customer service, or, at least provide us with a link to `texMemo.cls`.

Comment: If the error is "Missing `\begin{document}`", that means the error is in the preamble.  (Any error messages after that won't be helpful.)  Since you have loaded only one package, the error must be in the changes you made to the document class.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the texMemo class file has been included if you open the overleaf document as template

Comment: Not for those who are not users, i.e. there is *no* free access. Please contact the overleaf support to solve an overleaf problem.

Comment: Arrrrghhhh !!!!!

Comment: [Google](https://github.com/uberj/WR327/blob/master/Proposal/texMemo.cls) is remarkable. But on reflection, I think you want to thank the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100921091749/http://www.oak-tree.us/2010/08/02/texmemo/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If this is the class the OP is using, then one of the problems is that `\email` is not defined. Nor is `\printbibliography`.

Answer (score 2):

*[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]*

A copy of `texMemo.cls` can be downloaded from a link at https://texblog.org/2012/03/07/writing-a-memo-in-latex/. This is slightly different from the version uploaded to Overleaf as the "INFO 1200 Policy Memo", in that the "INFO 1200" one loads `mathptmx` instead of `palatino`, and additionally loads `hyperref`, `titlesec`, `biblatex`, `inputenc`. The "core" macros for creating the fields for a memo are unchanged.

The Overleaf template works fine out of the box. Looking at your code, and comparing to the sample code provided by that template (can be viewed with "View source" on the Overleaf template page): you can't use `\author`, `\title`, `\email` with this class. Instead, you must use `\memofrom`, `\memoto`, `\memore`, e.g.

```
\memofrom{Name (author's email)}
\memoto{Target recipients; is optional}
\memore{Discovering}
```